# Service with DependsOn is not being set correctly in Inno Setup via CreateService function

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm creating an installer for my app with Inno Setup and as part of the install it needs to install several services. For that I'm using the following code:

```pascal
Dependency := '';
if Depends then begin
  Dependency := 'DependencyServiceName';
end;

if not IsServiceInstalled(ServiceName) then begin
  if not InstallService(
           '"' + Path + '"', ServiceName, ServiceName, Description,
           SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, StartType, False, Dependency) then begin   
    Result := False;
    FailedSoExit('Failed to install the ' + Name + ' service.');
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

The relevant method is:

```pascal
function CreateService(
  hSCManager : HANDLE; lpServiceName, lpDisplayName : string;
  dwDesiredAccess, dwServiceType, dwStartType, dwErrorControl: cardinal;
  lpBinaryPathName, lpLoadOrderGroup: String; lpdwTagId : cardinal;
  lpDependencies, lpServiceStartName, lpPassword :string): cardinal;
external 'CreateServiceW@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function InstallService(
  FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;
  ServiceType, StartType : cardinal; Delayed : Boolean;
  Dependency: String) : Boolean;
var
  hSCM : HANDLE;
  hService : HANDLE;
begin
  hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
  Result := false;
  if hSCM <> 0 then begin
    hService := CreateService(
      hSCM, ServiceName, DisplayName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, ServiceType,
      StartType, 0, FileName, '', 0, Dependency, '', '');
    if hService <> 0 then begin
      Result := true;
      // Win2K & WinXP supports additional description text for services
      if Description<> '' then
        RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'System\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + ServiceName, 'Description', Description);
      if Delayed then            
        RegWriteDWordValue(HKLM, 'System\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + ServiceName, 'DelayedAutostart', 1);
      CloseServiceHandle(hService)
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
  end;
end;
```

This has always been working and even now when I run through the compiler everything works fine with `Dependency` having the right name. However, on the test machine I'm installing it on it now seems to add random stuff after it so `DependsOn` in the registry will look something like (where `{installPath}` is the path Inno Setup is installing it):

```
DependencyServiceName
£$%
)
{installPath}
```

This is obviously causing the services to fail to start as the 3 extra "dependencies" don't exist as services.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation of `CreateService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew) says, the `lpDependencies` parameter needs to be *"double null-terminated"*.

So if your code ever worked, if was just by an accident.

This should do:

```pascal
Dependency := Dependency + #0;
```